# JMS serializer, error during adding event subscriber

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I try to add EventSubscriber but I when I register subscriber in services I have an error: "undefined offset 0"

//services.yml

```
AppBundle\Subscribers\NoticePostSerializeSubscriber:
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_subscriber, event: serializer.post_serialize}
```

Subscriber

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Subscribers;

use JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\ObjectEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class NoticePostSerializeSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'event' => 'serializer.post_serialize',
                'method' => 'onPostSerialize',
                'class' => 'AppBundle\\Entity\\Notice', // if no class, subscribe to every serialization
                'format' => 'json', // optional format
                'priority' => 0, // optional priority
            ),
        );
    }

    public function onPostSerialize(ObjectEvent $event)
    {
    }
}
```

If I remove definition in servies, error disappear.

If my NoticePostSerializerSubscriber implements

> \JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface

I have following error:

> Service "AppBundle\Subscribers\NoticePostSerializeSubscriber" must
>   implement interface
>   "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface".

But If I change interface to

> Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface

I had error I mention above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are registering it the wrong way.

For an event subscriber there is no need to configure "event" in your services.yml, because this is handled inside `getSubscribedEvents()`, so remove your "event" property.

Jms serializer event subscribers are not Symfony kernel event subscribers, so change your service tags to:

```
tags:
  - { name: jms_serializer.event_subscriber }
```

Next, your class must implement`JMS\Serializer\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface`, not Symfony's EventSubscriberInterface